# Do I need a UK transit visa to travel from Sweden to the USA?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, british-airways, bangladeshi-citizens, swedish-residents

I am from Bangladesh and studying at Linkoping University, Sweden. I have a Swedish residence permit and a USA tourist visa.

During the Christmas holidays I am planning to travel to Miami with British Airways. On my return flight I will have a long transit of 20 hours. So in this context, do I need a UK transit visa?